# Finding a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue- Do row operations alter the eigenspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let A=$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2 & 0\\-4 & 5 & 0\\ -24 & 12 & 3\end{bmatrix}$ and λ=3.

Find a basis for the eigenspace of A corresponding to λ.

Sol'n:

We find vectors $\bar x$ s.t. (A-λI)$\bar x$=$\bar 0$

(A-3λ)$\bar x$=$\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 2 & 0\\-4 & 2 & 0\\ -24 & 12 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

My problems arise following this point- I obtain two different solution sets using two different methods of solving the problem.

Method 1:

From the above matrix, we obtain the equation

$-4x_1+2x_2=0 => x_2=2x_1 $

Let $x_2=s$ and $x_3=t$. Then solutions $\bar x$ are of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1/2s\\s\\t\end{bmatrix}$=$s$$\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$+$t$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, so a basis of the eigenspace of A corresponding to λ is the set $\begin{bmatrix}1/2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

My book says that $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\6\end{bmatrix}$,$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$ is one possible basis of the eigenspace corresponding to 3.

Are linear combinations of basis vectors themselves bases?

Method 2:

Given the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-4 & 2 & 0\\-4 & 2 & 0\\ -24 & 12 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, we row reduce to obtain $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

This gives us the system
$x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=t$ for any $t$.

Then solutions are of the form $\bar x$=$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$, and so our basis is $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

This result is evidently incorrect. Did the row operations that I performed alter the eigenspace of A?

Comment: after subtracting off $3I,$ the matrix becomes rank one, meaning two-dimensional space of genuine eigenvectors. Also, as to your question, since you are using column eigenvectors, row operations do NOT alter the eigenvectors. Under Method 2, you row reduced incorrectly, no idea how you did that.

Comment: Thanks, @WillJagy! I apologize for messing up with my row ops- I'll check my arithmetic using Wolfram Alpha in future questions.

Comment: should be  $\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1/2 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.